# On MacOs Electron BrowserWindow.LoadURL not working

Tags: electron

i am new to electron.
i used Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder to create base project.
in window BrowserWindow.LoadURL it work.
but on macos BrowserWindow.LoadURL not working.
macos version 10.10.5,
electron version 11.4.7

```
        try {
        //it not working on macos
        await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    } catch (err) {
        //can't catch any err on macos
        console.log(`loadURL err, url: ${process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL}, info: ${err}`)
    }
```

i searched a lot for the answer, but didn't get any answer for this.
can any suggest a solution for this? any help will be appreciated.

[run electron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPpn6.png)

[safari loads url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLv1p.png)

Comment: Do you see any errors? Did you initialize a new BrowserWindow and bind it to `win`? A simple example can be found in the documentation. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window

Comment: i didn't see any errors, yet,it use  Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder to create a base project, it also
 initialize a new BrowserWindow and bind it to win

Comment: Why did you put it in the try/catch block? Try to use instance events instead of asynchronously waiting for loadURL. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#instance-events

Comment: And what is the value of the process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL? Make sure that it is a valid URL that is publicly accessible.

Comment: i am sure value of process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL is a valid URL(localhost:8098), copy the url to Safari

Comment: use instance events instead of asynchronously waiting for loadURL, it also not working

Comment: i using try/catch block to catch error when trigger, but i can't catch any errors

Comment: Please read the following guide so that you can ask better questions in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the code sandbox doest'n supported electron, i post the whole code from the file to github, it repository is https://github.com/SilverStudio1985/base-electron.git

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console or in the server terminal? Does the app actually runs, or it just returns error? Do you only see white screen? Does the localhost loads when you try it in an actual browser? What happens when you remove await before the loadURL function?

Comment: no, i didn't see any errors in the console or in the server terminal. nothing error return. yes, i only see white screen. i try loads localhost in safari browser, it work. the loadURL function return Promise<void>, when i remove await before it, nothing happens and didn't catch any errors. i also use 'did-finish-load' and 'did-fail-load' event to listen the url loaded, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the loadURL function...

```
if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
} else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
}
```

Try to add this code block to check if the content of the page is ready or if it has finished loading. If it is, show the window and focus on it.

```
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  if (!win) {
    throw new Error('`win` is not defined');
  }
  if (process.env.START_MINIMIZED) {
    win.minimize();
  } else {
    win.show();
    win.focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: [did-finish-load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLv1p.png),  nothing happens.

Comment: How do you specify the WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL before you run the app, or what is the actual command that you use when you start the application? It is possible that the env is empty, so it defaults to index.html.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL, even if I load a web URL, such as [GitHub](https://github.com), it doesn't working. you can get it from the Image link([Load Web Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2fU1.png))

Comment: It can be the problem. It is possible that the environment variable is not actually added. Try to console.log to the if block.

Comment: print the [environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovzKY.png) before loadURL,  any problem?

Comment: when i reinstall mac os it working, it should be environment variable problem.